# React slick height issue when ading slick items dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I am using the [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) slider to display a set of images. after the user crosses some slide position I am calling another API and appending the new results with the existing results using old.concat(new) stored in component state. Each time when the API is called, the slider displays 2 rows(its height is changed) and then adjust its height again.
Once the API data is added to the array, is there is a glitch that disturbs the slider and then fixes after few seconds? How do I fix this issue?

I created codesandbox to replicate the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-forked-ub5fy

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue,
The only workaround for me is to set **lazyLoad** to true from settings.

```
 const settings = {
                   lazyLoad: true
                  }
```

[React-Slick LazyLoad](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/lazy-load)